Keycloak Connect Integration with Electron App
I'm new to Keycloak and having a hard time integrating my Electron Application to have access to protected API.
Here is what my code looks like in the main.js:
const { app, BrowserWindow, globalShortcut, ipcMain } = require('electron');
const url = require('url');
const path = require('path');
const session = require('express-session');
const Keycloak = require('keycloak-connect');

// Keycloak Setup
const memoryStore = new session.MemoryStore();
const keycloakConfig = {
  realm: 'my-realm',
  'auth-server-url': 'https://my-keycloak-server/auth', 
  'ssl-required': 'external',
  resource: 'my-client-id', 
  'public-client': true,
  'confidential-port': 0,
"credentials": {
    "secret":'my-secret'
  }
};
const keycloak = new Keycloak({ store: memoryStore }, keycloakConfig);

// Function to handle application readiness
async function onReady() {
  globalShortcut.register('alt+tab', () => {
    return false;
  });

  // Create a new BrowserWindow instance
  win = new BrowserWindow({
    width: 1920,
    height: 1080,
    frame: false,
    kiosk: true,
    isTrusted: true,
    webPreferences: {
      preload: path.join(__dirname, 'preload.js'),
    },
  });

  // Load the frontend
  win.loadURL(url.format({
    pathname: path.join(__dirname, 'dist/frontend/index.html'),
    protocol: 'file:',
    slashes: true,
  }));

  // Reload event listener
  ipcMain.on('reload', (event, arg) => {
    console.log("Reload");
    win.loadURL(url.format({
      pathname: path.join(__dirname, 'dist/frontend/index.html'),
      protocol: 'file:',
      slashes: true,
    }));
  });
}

// Start the Electron app
app.on('ready', onReady);


And here is my error:
localhost:3200/api/items:1
Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 500 (Internal Server Error)
